# Accessing elements of a ResultSet with only one tuple, returns exceptions

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, resultset

When I carry out the following operations:

```
public Product getProductById(long productId) throws DaoException {

    Connection con = DBManager.connect();
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        statement = con.prepareStatement(QUERY_PROD_BY_ID);
        statement.setLong(1, productId);

        rs = statement.executeQuery();
        //rs.first();
        Product product = new Product();

        product.setProductId(rs.getLong("product_id"));
        product.setProductImage(rs.getString("image"));
        product.setProductBrand(rs.getString("brand"));
        product.setProductModel(rs.getString("model_no"));
        product.setProductPrice(rs.getFloat("price"));
        product.setProductSummary(rs.getString("summary"));
        product.setProductStock(rs.getInt("stock"));
        product.setProductCategory(rs.getLong("category_id"));
        product.setProductCreationTime(rs
                .getTimestamp("product_creation_time"));
        product.setProductStatus(ProductStatusState.values()[rs
                .getInt("product_status")]);
        product.setType(ProductType.values()[rs.getInt("type")]);

        return product;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new DaoException(e);

    } finally {
        DBManager.closeAll(statement, rs);

    }
}
```

I get an error which says

```
 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ResultSet not positioned properly, perhaps you need to call next.
```

My ProductId is my primary key and hence only one row will be present in the ResultSet. When I set a

```
while(rs.next){...}
```

it returns me null. What should I do?

Comment: Obviously you will have to do rs.next(). Can you show the code when you are getting null

Comment: When read for first time from any newly opened ResultSet a call to next() is mandatory to move ResultSet pointer on first record.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in previous comments, when you execute a query that returns a result set the initial position of the cursor is before the first row of data in the result set.  Calling rs.next() will move your cursor to your first row and allow you to access the data that was returned with the rs.getXXX() methods.